# Why is a MySQL join returning a circular set?

Tags: mysql, join

Lets say I have two tables:

table `english` which has two columns,  `id` and `letter`:

```
1,a
2,b
3,c
```

table `greek` which has two columns,  `id` and `letter`:

```
1,alpha
2,beta
3,gamma
```

Ok so I execute the query `select * from english limit 1,5`
and i get:

```
2,b
3,c
```

Which is what I would expect.  Now I try `select english.id,english.letter,greek.letter from english join greek on greek.id=english.id order by english.id asc limit 1,5`

```
2,b,beta
3,c,gama
1,a,alpha
2,b,beta
3,c,gama
```

**What!?**  why is this set circular?  Ok well,  this next query works as I would expect:

`select english.id,english.letter,greek.letter from english join greek on greek.id=english.id group by english.id order by english.id asc limit 1,5`

```
2,b,beta
3,c,gama
```

**So what the hell is going on here?** Why do I need to add the `group by english.id` for the set to behavior like I would expect?

Comment: Using a LIMIT clause without an ORDER BY doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Vincent Savard agreed that was a typo,  i had an order by in the real query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you have duplicate rows in your `greek` table.

It works fine when I try it on MySQL 5.5.20: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/163cd/4).

Here's an example where I have deliberately inserted duplicate rows in the `greek` table and it gives exactly the same results as you get: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b548/1)

Comment: i don't think so,  because then i would have to add a having clause...  +1 sqlfiddle is awesome!  I updated it a bit and it looks more like what i was getting,  but it isn't circular...  Also`g_id = english.id` wasn't the query it was actually `r_id = english.id` which returns the proper set...  I am even more confused now.

Comment: @Rook: Just run a `SELECT * FROM greek` and you'll see if it has duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

LIMIT applies to the whole query. If you want to limit particular table, apply limit to it first

```
select english.id,english.letter,greek.letter 
from (select * from english limit 1,5) as english
join greek on greek.id=english.id
```

And you should put ORDER BY on LIMIT clause, unless it's something random